# "Command not found" for all commands in Kali

Tags: bash, kali-linux, linux-terminal

I'm running Kali Linux 64 bit on my computer. I keep getting the message:

> '-bash: command not found'

It doesn't matter what command I type (e.g., `ifconfig` or `airmon-ng`).

Is there a way of fixing this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you have destroyed your path. Can you execute an editor? `/bin/vi`?

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenter said: Something is wrong with your [Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), possibly the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Many things can cause this, but here are a few to check:

`echo $PATH` If it's empty, it needs to be filled, in addition to finding out why it's empty.

I remember first getting this around 15 years ago when I was first starting to learn unix-like OSes: I managed to learn the hard way the dangers of `rm -rf`, and I deleted my home directory. (FreeBSD 3.3, if my memory serves me right)

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes the space is empty. what should i do to fix this problem? thanks

Comment: do you know how to fix this ( command not found ) problem. if so could you please give me steps to fix this problem thanks.

Comment: allso, if I boot kali linux on a new computer would this problem still exist. and what is the easiest wat to solve the problem.

Comment: Write `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"` and you will have it in your current session. Is your `/etc/environment` empty? Does `ls ~` give any output?